# Custom Shipping Method - Retrieve Shipping address in collectRates

Tags: magento2

I'm currently working on a custom shipping method for Magento 2 and I'm facing a problem : I don't know how to retrieve the shipping address.

I tried first with something like this in the `collectRates` method :

```
$city = $request->getDestCity();
$street = $request->getDestStreet();
```

But it didn't worked (`$city` and `$street` are empty).

That's strange because I don't have any issue whit the `getDestPostcode()` method.

Is there a another way to retrieve the shipping address ?

Thanks.

Comment: I think it might be a bug.

Comment: facing same issue need shipping address in collectRates

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug, see the following link on github: 
[issue 3789](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/3789)

Basically the additional address fields need to be added to the payload within:

```
module-checkout/view/frontend/web/model/js/shipping-rate-processor/new-address.js
```

Also, you'll need to create another `serviceUrl` that will call a function that will hold the full address payload and adds the full address to the request.

Answer (score 0):

please try this code :

```
<?php

namespace namespace\modulename\Model\Carrier;

use Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\Error;
use Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateRequest;
use Magento\Shipping\Model\Carrier\AbstractCarrierOnline;
use Magento\Shipping\Model\Carrier\CarrierInterface;
use Magento\Shipping\Model\Rate\Result;
use Magento\Shipping\Model\Simplexml\Element;
use Magento\Framework\Xml\Security;

class Demo extends AbstractCarrierOnline implements CarrierInterface
{
    protected $_request;
    protected $_result;
    protected $_localeFormat;
    protected $_code;
    protected $_logger;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
        \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\ErrorFactory $rateErrorFactory,
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
        Security $xmlSecurity,
        \Magento\Shipping\Model\Simplexml\ElementFactory $xmlElFactory,
        \Magento\Shipping\Model\Rate\ResultFactory $rateFactory,
        \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\MethodFactory $rateMethodFactory,
        \Magento\Shipping\Model\Tracking\ResultFactory $trackFactory,
        \Magento\Shipping\Model\Tracking\Result\ErrorFactory $trackErrorFactory,
        \Magento\Shipping\Model\Tracking\Result\StatusFactory $trackStatusFactory,
        \Magento\Directory\Model\RegionFactory $regionFactory,
        \Magento\Directory\Model\CountryFactory $countryFactory,
        \Magento\Directory\Model\CurrencyFactory $currencyFactory,
        \Magento\Directory\Helper\Data $directoryData,
        \Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockRegistryInterface $stockRegistry,
        \Magento\Framework\Locale\FormatInterface $localeFormat,
        \Demo\Shipping\Model\Api\DemoAPI $DemoApi,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_localeFormat = $localeFormat;
        $this->_DemoApi = $DemoApi;
        $this->_code = 'Demo';
        parent::__construct(
            $scopeConfig,
            $rateErrorFactory,
            $logger,
            $xmlSecurity,
            $xmlElFactory,
            $rateFactory,
            $rateMethodFactory,
            $trackFactory,
            $trackErrorFactory,
            $trackStatusFactory,
            $regionFactory,
            $countryFactory,
            $currencyFactory,
            $directoryData,
            $stockRegistry,
            $data
        );
    }

    protected function _doShipmentRequest(\Magento\Framework\DataObject $request) {}

    public function getAllowedMethods(){
    }

    public function collectRates(RateRequest $request)
    {
        if (!$this->getConfigFlag('active')) {
            return false;
        }
        $result = $this->_rateFactory->create();

        // Getting delivery address street
        $street_address = $request->getDestStreet();

        // Prepare address 1
        $address_line = explode(PHP_EOL, $street_address);
        $address1 = !empty($address_line[0]) ? $address_line[0] : $street_address;
        $address2 = !empty($address_line[1]) ? $address_line[1] : '';

        $zip = $request->getDestPostcode();
        $city = $request->getDestCity();
        $country_code = $request->getDestCountryId();
        $state = $request->getDestRegionCode();

        // Prepare delivery_address for quote
        $delivery_address = array(
            'address_1' => $address1,
            'address_2' => $address2,
            'zip' => $zip,
            'city' => $city,
            'country_code' => $country_code,
            'state' => $state
        );

        // Getting cart items
        $items = $request->getAllItems();

        $price = $request->getPackageValue();
        $weight = $request->getPackageWeight();

        $shipping_rates = $this->_demoApi->quoteRates(
            $delivery_address,
            $items,
            $price,
            $weight
        );
        if ($shipping_rates) {
            foreach ($shipping_rates as $rate) {
                if ($rate['shipping_rate']['require_drop_point']) {
                    $droppoints = $this->_DemoApi->getDroppoints(
                        $rate['shipping_rate']['id'],
                        $address1,
                        $zip,
                        $city,
                        $country_code,
                        $state
                    );
                    if (isset($droppoints) && is_array($droppoints)) {

                        // Get maximum number of droppoints from settings
                        $dp_limit = $this->getDroppointLimit();
                        if ((int)$dp_limit > 0) {
                            $dp_limit = (int)$dp_limit;
                        } else {
                            $dp_limit = 5;
                        }

                        // Loop through droppoints and generate shipping rate for each
                        foreach($droppoints as $index => $droppoint) {
                            if (((int)$index + 1) > $dp_limit)
                                break;

                            $method = $this->_rateMethodFactory->create();

                            $method->setCarrier($this->_code);
                            $method->setCarrierTitle($rate['carrier_name']);

                            $method_code = $rate['shipping_rate']['id']."_".$droppoint['drop_point_id'];

                            $method->setMethod($method_code);
                            $method->setMethodTitle(
                                $rate['shipping_rate']['name'].' '.
                                $droppoint['name'].' '.
                                $droppoint['address_1'].' '.
                                $droppoint['country_code'].'-'.
                                $droppoint['zip']
                            );

                            $method->setPrice($rate['price']);
                            $method->setCost($rate['price']);

                            $result->append($method);
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    $method = $this->_rateMethodFactory->create();

                    $method->setCarrier($this->_code);
                    $method->setCarrierTitle($rate['carrier_name']);

                    $method_code = $rate['shipping_rate']['id'];

                    $method->setMethod($method_code);
                    $method->setMethodTitle($rate['shipping_rate']['name']);

                    $method->setPrice($rate['price']);
                    $method->setCost($rate['price']);

                    $result->append($method);
                }
            }
        }
        return $result;
    }

    private function getDroppointLimit() {
        return $this->_scopeConfig->getValue(
            'carriers/Demo/droppoint_limit',
            \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE
        );
    }
}
```